# Indexing during assignment

Tags: matlab, indexing, octave

Say I have this sample data

```
A =
1.0000     6.0000   180.0000    12.0000
1.0000     5.9200   190.0000    11.0000
1.0000     5.5800   170.0000    12.0000
1.0000     5.9200   165.0000    10.0000
2.0000     5.0000   100.0000     6.0000
2.0000     5.5000   150.0000     8.0000
2.0000     5.4200   130.0000     7.0000
2.0000     5.7500   150.0000     9.0000
```

I wish to calculate the variance of each column, grouped by class (the first column).

I have this working with the following code, but it uses hard coded indices, requiring knowledge of the number of samples per class and they must be in specific order.

Is there a better way to do this?

```
variances = zeros(2,4);
variances = [1.0 var(A(1:4,2)), var(A(1:4,3)), var(A(1:4,4));
             2.0 var(A(5:8,2)), var(A(5:8,3)), var(A(5:8,4))];

disp(variances);

1.0 3.5033e-02   1.2292e+02   9.1667e-01
2.0 9.7225e-02   5.5833e+02   1.6667e+00
```

Comment: Also, if I could avoid storing the class number (1.0 2.0 etc) directly and just store the 3 results in the relevant row of variances that would be even better.

Comment: Let's we find the class first and store that into the variable. Next we find `var()` for each column group by that class. Will that do for you?

Comment: I can guarantee that the class identifier starts at 1 and is continuous

Comment: @bonCodigo hard to say till I see what you're suggesting :) I'm new to matlab

Comment: @Iain is the class number 1, 2, 3, ... or can it be 1.3, 2, 4.5, ... Also is the number of rows for given class same (in your example you have 3 rows for each class 1 and 2).

Comment: @mythealias no the number of rows wouldn't be the same, and I suppose neither would the number of columns. for the class number they just have to be different

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Separate the class labels and the data into different variables.

```
cls = A(:, 1);
data = A(:, 2:end);
```

Get the list of class labels

```
labels = unique(cls);
```

Compute the variances

```
variances = zeros(length(labels), 3);
for i = 1:length(labels)
  variances(i, :) = var(data(cls == labels(i), :)); % note the use of logical indexing
end
```

Comment: this is really great - I've not seen the use of a boolean expression in a matrix lookup like that before. many thanks. learning one question at a time..

Comment: @Dima ahh I see. I misunderstood the question. I have removed my comment.

Comment: @Iain For more information on logical indexing, see this: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html?s_tid=doc_12b#bq7egb6-1

Comment: @dima ha, I'm reading something similar right now. thanks again

Answer (score 2):

I've done a fair bit of this type of stuff over the years, but to be able to judge, better vs. best, it would help to know what you expect to change in the data set or structure.

Otherwise, if no change is anticipated and the hard code works, stick with it.

Comment: I was really more interested in learning matlab than this specific case, but I know exctly what you mean about sticking with what works :)

Comment: I like Dima's response for that purpose.  That approach has worked for me before as well.

Answer (score 0):

Easy, peasy. Use [consolidator](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8354-consolidator). It is on the file exchange.

```
A = [1.0000     6.0000   180.0000    12.0000
1.0000     5.9200   190.0000    11.0000
1.0000     5.5800   170.0000    12.0000
1.0000     5.9200   165.0000    10.0000
2.0000     5.0000   100.0000     6.0000
2.0000     5.5000   150.0000     8.0000
2.0000     5.4200   130.0000     7.0000
2.0000     5.7500   150.0000     9.0000];

[C1,var234] = consolidator(A(:,1),A(:,2:4),@var)
C1 =
     1
     2
var234 =
     0.035033       122.92      0.91667
     0.097225       558.33       1.6667
```

We can test the variances produced, since we know the grouping.

```
var(A(1:4,2:4))
ans =
     0.035033       122.92      0.91667

var(A(5:8,2:4))
ans =
     0.097225       558.33       1.6667
```

It is efficient too.